# How to select the closest element by first part of classname?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this part of a table

```
<tr class="getmoreinfo_19">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
             <i class="far fa-window-close getmoreinfo_x"></i>txt
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to hide this on click at the `"<i class="far fa-window-close getmoreinfo_x"></i>"` icon.

For that I want to toggle a `display:none` class.

My problem is, that I don't know how I can select the closest "tr" which has the classname who begins with "getmoreinfo_"?

Is it possible and if its how?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why is the TR class name important? Don't you just want to find the parent TR?

Comment: this class is currently display:block; on click i want to change to display:none.
There are a lot of rows, every row has another "getmoreinfo_"+rownumber

Comment: if you're using javascript, then try `.closest('tr[class^="getmoreinfo_"]') ` , please note this is assuming the clicked target is `<i>`

Comment: Note: IE and some versions of IE Edge do not support `closest()`, [browser-compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#search=closest). If these browsers do not need to be supported, ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using javascript, then try  `.closest('tr[class^="getmoreinfo_"]')` ,

Please note this is assuming the clicked target is `<i>` and the `tr` element always has only class `getmoreinfo_` **at the beginning**. In case your `tr` has more classes, consider using this:

`.closest('tr[class*="getmoreinfo_"]')`

```
<table>
  <tr class="getmoreinfo_1" data-row="1">
    <td>
      <div class="item"><span></span><i class="icon-x">X</i></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="getmoreinfo_1" data-row="2">
    <td>
      <div class="item"><span></span><i class="icon-x">X</i></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="getmoreinfo_1" data-row="3">
    <td>
      <div class="item"><span></span><i class="icon-x">X</i></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
(function(){
  const icons = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-x');

  function clickHandler(event) {
    const row = event.currentTarget.closest('tr[class*="getmoreinfo_"]');
    console.log(`clicked: ${row.getAttribute('data-row')}`)
  }

  for(const icon of icons) {
    icon.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  }
})();
```

Hope this help